# How is Set.toString() implemented?

Tags: java

The `toString()` method is not overridden in `Set` or its hierarchy, so how are the elements printed?

```
import java.lang.Math;
import java.util.HashSet;
class Hello{

public String name= ""; 

Hello(String name){

    this.name = name;   

}


public static void main(String args[]){

 Hello h1 = new Hello("first");
 Hello h2 = new Hello("second");
 Hello h3 = new Hello("third");
 Hello h4 = new Hello("fourth");
 Hello h5 = new Hello("fourth");

 HashSet hs = new HashSet(); 
 hs.add(h1);
 hs.add(h2);
 hs.add(h3);
 hs.add(h4);
 hs.add(h5);

 //hs.add(h5);
 //hs.add(null);

    System.out.println("elements in hashset"+hs);
      //System.out.println("elements in hashset"+hs.contains());
     //System.out.println("elements in hashset"+hs.contains(new Hello("who")));
    } 

    public boolean equals(Object obj){
        System.out.println("In Equals");
        System.out.println(name+"=====equals======"+((Hello)obj).name);
        if(name.equals(((Hello)obj).name))
            return true;
        else
             return false;
    }

    public int hashCode(){
        System.out.println("----In Hashcode----"+name); 
        return name.hashCode();
    }
}
```

> ```
> Output :----In Hashcode----first
> ----In Hashcode----second
> ----In Hashcode----third
> ----In Hashcode----fourth
> ----In Hashcode----fourth
> In Equals
> fourth=====equals======fourth
> ----In Hashcode----fourth
> ----In Hashcode----second
> ----In Hashcode----third
> ----In Hashcode----first
> elements in hashset[Hello@b4616a1a, Hello@c9
> ]
> ```

Also When I print hashset the hashcode method is called for each of the elements ?Does it mean the iterator calls this method ?

Comment: then its obvious that you haven't checked the whole hierarchy. see the class AbstractCollection.

Comment: I just see code (kind of) and no question.

Comment: @Manoj: No; he's checking the wrong hierarchy.  `Set` doesn't inherit `AbstractCollection`.

Comment: @SLaks but HashSet does.

Comment: @Manoj: Exactly.  He's checking the wrong hierarchy.

Comment: `Set` does not have any implementation. The code executed when `HashSet.toString()` is called is in `AbstractCollection`. You can see this in the API docs from `HashSet` where it says: "Methods inherited from class java.util.AbstractCollection"

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`Set` is an interface.
It cannot override methods.

You're using the `HashSet` **class**, which inherits [`AbstractCollection.toString()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/AbstractCollection.java#AbstractCollection.toString%28%29)

Answer (score 10):

The Set implementations inherit toString from [AbstractCollection](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html). The Set elements are output as a string list separated by commas.

Comment: Also When I print hashset the hashcode method is called for each of the elements ?Does it mean the iterator calls this method ?

Comment: `hashCode()` is called in the get and put methods of `HashMap`, which `HashSet` uses internally (actually `LinkedHashMap`). See http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/HashMap.java if you're interested.

Answer (score 2):

HashSet does returns comma separated strings as overrided by its super class `AbstractSet.`

No surprises!