# Where will be the definition of Collection methods resides?

Tags: java, collections, interface

I know Collection is an interface containing abstract methods such as add(), addAll(),..
and Collections is a class containing static methods such as addAll(),max(),.. which extends Object.
and
Collection implements interface Iterable.

Interface since it can contain only abstract methods would contain only abstract method(which won't have definition).

So, my question is if List,Set,.. are implementing Collection interface then where will be the definitions of methods like add(), addAll(), remove(), contains(), iterator(),.. written?

Comment: In the concrete classes imlplementing these interfaces: ArrayList, LinkedList, HashSet, etc.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How is Set.toString() implemented?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5937869/how-is-set-tostring-implemented)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`List` and `Set` don't implement `Collection`, since they are also interfaces (which extend the `Collection` interface).

The implementations are in the implementing classes, such as `ArrayList`, `LinkedList`, `HashSet`, etc...